# Double condition with Xpath selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I want to access elements of all balises that find like this : `<div class='xxxx' the text >`

I did as this with Xpath:

```
textSearch = 'the text'
hometeam = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='xxxx'] and //div[contains(text(),'"+ textSearch +"')]")
```

But this not works and casting this exception : `TypeError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The result is not a node set, and therefore cannot be converted to the desired type.`

How do ?

Comment: `//div[@class='xxxx' and contains(text(), 'justin')]`

Comment: Your XPath returns boolean value while Selenium supports WebElement only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combine the conditions within the `[...]`

E.g., `//div[@class='xxxx' and contains(text(), 'justin')]`.

Demo [here](http://xpather.com/IqVGDT2p)

Comment: Small addition: an alternative to "and" can also be attaching one predicate to another `//div[@class='xxxx'][contains(text(), 'justin')]`

Comment: I did not know that. Thanks, @AlexandraDudkina.